# Open .net framework 4.5 project in VS 2022. Is there any workaround?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-10, .net-framework-version

Is there anyway to open and work on `.net framework 4.5` project in `visual studio 2022`.

May be problem is not with VS2022 but as `.net framework 4.5` developer pack is not available any more .. my project can not be changed target version .. Is there any workaround?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Upgrade. .NET Framework 4.5 went out of support years ago. The earliest supported version is 4.5.2 but even that goes out of support in a few months. The lowest supported version will be 4.6.2

Comment: See: https://thomaslevesque.com/2021/11/12/building-a-project-that-target-net-45-in-visual-studio-2022

Answer (score 377, accepted):

- Download [Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net45](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.netframework.referenceassemblies.net45) from nuget.org
- Open the package as zip (or rename the package file and change its extension from .nupkg to .zip then open it)
- copy the files from `build\.NETFramework\v4.5\` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5`
- Close Visual Studio and then reopen it

For more details: [Building a project that target .NET Framework 4.5 in Visual Studio 2022](https://thomaslevesque.com/2021/11/12/building-a-project-that-target-net-45-in-visual-studio-2022/)

Comment: I automated the steps in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70398706/569302

Comment: This also works when targeting .Net 4.0, just download the .net40 nuget package, and copy files to \.NETFramework\v4.0 folder. Restart VS then open the project and it works just fine.

Comment: *Note*: After downloading you've to rename the file name from `.nupkg` to  `.zip` than the rest of the process is  as mentioned in this answer.  Maybe it is known to the maximum of you but It could save hours for someone like me. That's why putting the comment here.

Comment: It does not work for .Net 3.5

Comment: Remember to close and re-open Visual Studio after this as the change doesn't automatically take effect.

Comment: This also works for .Net Framework 4.5.1 and for any other version. Just get the Nuget package for the version of .Net framework you need, and unzip and copy the files in the corresponding folder on your PC

Comment: Even if you have a v4.5 folder already, move those files to a new folder _BK and paste the files into the v4.5 folder.  Works perfect.  thank you!

Comment: Despite this being the _Accepted_ answer, it is honestly the _hard_ way. The one and **only** thing you need to do is reference the appropriate NuGet package. You do **not** need to explicitly download, extract it, or write any code for it to work. It will work with any project that supports NuGet or `packages.config`. The issue with this approach is that it requires elevation to write to a protected directory, may not work on a build server, and is not team-friendly. The package has MSBuild targets that _magically_ connects everything.

Comment: @ChrisMartinez really? the OP is clearly having a problem loading the project in the first place as well as most of who are coming here for the answer. so loading a nuget package into the project may not be the correct solution for the situation here.

Comment: @CME64 yes, really. The project doesn't load because the necessary .NET targeting pack was not found. The reference assemblies NuGet package includes all of the necessary files from the targeting pack and overrides the MSBuild properties and targets to use the NuGet file location instead of an installed location. I've expanded my answer with additional details, images, etc as well as a link to a working Gist.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. The files exist but the options for other frameworks simply don't show up in the "Target framework" dropdown at all.

Comment: Thank you @all for your kind comments and expressions of gratitude; I truly appreciate your feedback. However, I want to emphasize that the answer provided here is not originally mine but rather sourced from Thomas Levesque's blog. He deserves credit for his insightful contribution. I encourage you to visit his blog for more valuable insights and information (https://thomaslevesque.com) (https://stackoverflow.com/users/98713/thomas-levesque) (https://github.com/thomaslevesque).

Comment: really, this solution saved my life, a lot of thanks for sharing the solution @HusamEbish

Answer (score 20):

While all of the proposed, and even the accepted, solutions will work, none of them are the *preferred* approach.

The only thing you need to do is add a reference to the NuGet package as follows:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net40</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net40" Version="1.0.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

*Figure 1: C# project targeting .NET Framework 4.0 via reference assemblies*

You can make this change directly in the `*.csproj` or via the *Package Manager* UI in Visual Studio. The MSBuild extensions in the package will take care of the rest of the *magic*. There are no scripts to write, files to copy, or permissions to grant. This will work without elevation, which would be required to write under `%PROGRAMFILES%`.

Setting `PrivateAssets="All"` will make the package reference design-time only. It will not be picked up or included as a transitive dependency if your target also builds a NuGet package.

[image: .NET 4.0 console in VS2022]

*Figure 2: Project targeting .NET Framework 4.0 in the Visual Studio 2022 Solution Explorer*

Roslyn [Issue 56161: Remove .NET 4.5 Targeting Pack Requirement](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/56161#issuecomment-915450428) further confirms that this how you use reference assemblies when a targeting pack is not installed. This approach is useful any time you don't want to install a targeting pack or it's otherwise unavailable - say on a build server without Visual Studio.

#### The Proof

[image: .NET Targeting Packs]

*Figure 3: Older .NET targeting packs not installed or available*

I ran into the same issue after uninstalling Visual Studio 2019. The build worked as expected from Visual Studio and the CLI after adding this package reference.

#### Example

1. Download the files from the [.NET 4.0 Console using VS2022](https://gist.github.com/commonsensesoftware/6f2351f22764eafc8d9181078d941618) Gist to any folder
2. Open a developer prompt and navigate to the target folder
3. Execute `dotnet restore`
4. Open the project in Visual Studio 2022
5. Build and run the project

#### Additional Information

- Building from the command-line with `dotnet` or `msbuild` should be error and warning free
- You do **not** have to have the target .NET Framework version installed to build it, but you do to run it; including unit tests
- You *may* need to run **Clean** and/or manually delete `bin`, `obj`, and possibly `.vs` to clear out initial Visual Studio warnings
- You *may* need to perform an explicit NuGet restore (ex: `dotnet restore`) to clear initial Visual Studio warnings
- Visual Studio appears to require the target .NET Framework be installed
- The example shown targets .NET Framework 4.0 with .NET Framework 4.8 installed
- Targeting .NET Framework 2.0 or 3.5 compiled via command-line, but not Visual Studio, likely because I don't have them installed
- If Visual Studio is still giving you grief:

  - Add at least one supported target framework moniker (ex: `net48`)
  - Use Visual Studio Code (I prefer full VS, but it's an option)

Comment: Question. What if the web app in question doesn't actually contain a csproj file? Surely then, if you can't open the project to use the package manager UI; you're screwed?

Comment: The original question indicated C# and, hence, `*.csproj`. This approach, however, will work for any MSBuild project be it `*.vbproj` or a vanilla `*.proj`. Ultimately, you just need NuGet support. If you're using an older project system or have no project file at all, then you can use the NuGet CLI (e.g. `nuget.exe`) with `packages.config` to _install_ the package locally. If you're compiling .NET code with a Web App, MSBuild **must** be involved somewhere because that's how the compiler is integrated. Connecting package `*.targets` to your app will enable the _magic_.

Comment: Didn't work for me, so not as easy as you say it seems. Still gives the error on load and won't open the project after adding those lines to the csproj.

Comment: @BrentKilboy, you don't need to modify the project by hand unless you want to. I don't have enough context. If you have a Gist, repo, or some more context, I'm happy to elaborate. This _is_ the official way to for it to be performed. It's also possible your build state is dirty. It _might_ be worth clearing out `bin` and `obj`, then doing a project rebuild.

Comment: Do you think this solution is the most appropriate?  Would you really do this step if you had 1000 projects?

Comment: @HusamEbish yes - absolutely. You could easily add this to `Build.Directory.props` or Build.Directory.targets` once and all 1000+ projects would be updated.  This is how I manage legacy .NET Frameworks in big OSS projects. This is also how the .NET team manages it themselves.

Comment: VS considers this an "invalid expression" in the CSPROJ file: "([MSBuild]::VersionGreaterThanOrEquals(net40, 4.0))"

Comment: @DanielMöller it's not clear what you are trying to achieve, but that appears to be incorrect and is expected. `$(TargetFramework)` will return the TFM, whereas `$(TargetFrameworkVersion)` would return `v4.0`. You need to use a different property or function. You might also be looking for `GetTargetFrameworkVersion` or `IsTargetFrameworkCompatible`. Refer to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions

Comment: @ChrisMartinez ,  I'm trying to use your answer to target v4.0, that's all. It's not "me" who is using a function here, it's Visual Studio itself when it tries to load the project using that CSPROJ snippet.

Comment: Turns out I was missing the `Sdk` parameter in project. Now I'm facing other weird problems like 1 - The "ResolvePackageAssets" task was not given a value for the required parameter "TargetFramework". --- 2 - Duplicate 'Compile' items were included. The .NET SDK includes 'Compile' items from your project directory by default. You can either remove these items from your project file, or set the 'EnableDefaultCompileItems' property to 'false' if you want to explicitly include them in your project file. For more information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems. The duplicate items were: 'Class1

Comment: @DanielMöller if you have a repo or Gist that you can link to, that would easier. You can also ask a new SO question and link it. It will be hard to fully answer your question in this comment section.

Answer (score 12):

From the comments on the article linked from the answer about copying the files: "Install "Windows 8 SDK". And it can just install ".Net Framework 4.5 Software Development Kit". No other baggage."

This option was the quickest for me, as I can run an elevated installer easier than switching to elevated to write to the program files folders.

[image]

Comment: any link to the url?

Comment: @Moumit https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/

Comment: Very good for a build agent machine, but probably not very good for developer machines. Developers should upgrade such projects to .NET Framework 4.6.2 and above.

Comment: For anyone look for the sdksetup which contains le 4.5 Targeting pack. You have to go on the link provided by @Tronald and then go down to 'Earlier releases' and choose Windows 8 SDK > Install SDK. Here's the final link :https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/1/3/F1300C9C-A120-4341-90DF-8A52509B23AC/standalonesdk/sdksetup.exe

Comment: also in Internet Archive https://archive.org/details/windowssdk

Answer (score 5):

Another way to install *multiple* older targeting packs is to install Visual Studio 2019.

Note: it will delete them again if you uninstall VS2019, so take a copy of the ones you want and paste them back afterwards.

[image]

Comment: Not very good, as copying such files instead of installing from the original sources (SDK or Developer Packs) makes it hard to clean up.

Comment: @Lex Li I'm not sure what you mean.  A Visual Studio 2019 install is an original source.  And uninstalling it will clean the files up.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an automated solution. It follows the steps in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70109092/569302 When it copies the files a dialog may appear that you have to click to replace files that already exist

(**Note: You may need to update the "version" `"1.0.2"` to whatever is latest if there's a newer [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.netframework.referenceassemblies.net45)**)

Run `await DevHelpers.Download();`

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace j.Dev
{
    public class DevHelpers
    {
        public static async Task Download()
        {
            var version = "1.0.2";
            var name = "Framework45-" + DateTimeToFileString(DateTime.Now);
            var fileName = $"{name}.zip";
            var url = $"https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net45/{version}";
            await DownloadFile(fileName, url);
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(fileName, name);
            var from = Path.Join(name, @"build\.NETFramework\v4.5\");
            var to = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5";
            FileSystem.CopyDirectory(from, to, UIOption.AllDialogs);
        }

        private static string DateTimeToFileString(DateTime d)
        {
            return d.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss");
        }

        private static async Task DownloadFile(string fileName, string url)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(url);
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            using (var fs = new FileStream(
                fileName,
                FileMode.CreateNew))
            {
                await response.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my case I needed to download 4.0 AND 4.5, so here is the code that downloads both 4.0 and 4.5:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace j.Dev
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Example Usage: await DevHelpers.DownloadAndCopyFramework4_0And4_5();
    /// </summary>
    public class DevHelpers
    {
        public static async Task DownloadAndCopyFramework4_0And4_5()
        {
            await DownloadAndCopyFramework4_0();
            await DownloadAndCopyFramework4_5();
        }

        public static async Task DownloadAndCopyFramework4_5()
        {
            await DownloadAndCopyFrameworkGeneric("net45", "v4.5", "1.0.2");
        }

        public static async Task DownloadAndCopyFramework4_0()
        {
            await DownloadAndCopyFrameworkGeneric("net40", "v4.0", "1.0.2");
        }

        public static async Task DownloadAndCopyFrameworkGeneric(string netVersion, string folder, string nugetVersion)
        {
            var name = netVersion + "-" + DateTimeToFileString(DateTime.Now);
            var fileName = $"{name}.zip";
            var url = $"https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.{netVersion}/{nugetVersion}";
            await DownloadFile(fileName, url);
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(fileName, name);
            var from = Path.Join(name, @"build\.NETFramework\" + folder);
            var to = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\" + folder;
            FileSystem.CopyDirectory(from, to, UIOption.AllDialogs);
        }

        private static string DateTimeToFileString(DateTime d)
        {
            return d.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss");
        }

        private static async Task DownloadFile(string fileName, string url)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(url);
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            using (var fs = new FileStream(
                fileName,
                FileMode.CreateNew))
            {
                await response.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the script. I wanted both 4.0 and 4.5 as I have old projects for the class library and Winform app.

One question : Does the `"var version = "1.0.2"` or `("netx0", "vx.0", "1.0.2")` matter and is it latest as of today (even though the framework version in old)?

Comment: "Does the "var version = "1.0.2" or ("netx0", "vx.0", "1.0.2") matter" If I understand correctly: I provided two code solutions. It doesn't matter if you use the first (`var version = "1.0.2"`) or the second (`("net45", "v4.5", "1.0.2")`). I provided both because the first answers the question on this site precisely and the second may be helpful to others who are Googling.

Comment: "is it latest as of today (even though the framework version in old)" As of today it is the most recent NuGet package on this website: https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.netframework.referenceassemblies.net45 If you click "Versions" you can see the latest (Screenshot of NuGet website: https://ibb.co/Pc43zG5). An enhancement to the code I've written is to check that NuGet website (or do something) to see if there's a newer NuGet package version

Answer (score 4):

For .NET 4.0, this command will install it for you if you have the Visual Studio 2019 files cached:

```
msiexec.exe /i "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.4.TargetingPack,version=4.0.30319.1\netfx_dtp.msi" EXTUI=1
```

For .NET 4.5, this might work, though I haven't tried it:

```
msiexec.exe /i "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.4.5.2.TargetingPack,version=4.5.51651.1\netfx_452mtpack.msi" EXTUI=1
```

Comment: "if you have the Visual Studio 2019 files cached" - what do you mean by this? How do you ensure these are cached? the folders are there but there's no msi inside.

Comment: @Nyerguds: When you install VS2019 (or 2017, I think), the installer files are normally cached in that directory unless you tell it not to. If you don't have the files then perhaps it didn't need that component during the install? You can also use the installer with the [`layout` argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio) to have it cache files alongside the installer - then look inside that folder for these files.

Comment: My problem was actually creating a new project on older frameworks, and it turns out that the issue preventing me from selecting older frameworks was simply the new .csproj format they use. Starts with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` rather than the normal xml one with xmlns definition.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with a project targeting both .NET Framework 4.5.2 and .NET 6 in VS2022, Windows 11, and fixed it by downloading the developer pack directly from Microsoft. The accepted answer did not work for me.

I used the link suggested by the compiler error I got: https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks, and found 4.5.2 in the "out of support versions" section. It's in a collapsed pane so you have to click the "out of support" element.

Direct link: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net452-developer-pack-offline-installer

Answer (score 1):

A auto script in powershell to install the .NET Framework in VS22 (assuming is installed in the default path)

```bash
$isAdmin = ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)

if (-not $isAdmin) {
    Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "-File `"$PSCommandPath`""
    exit
}

$versions = @("net40", "net45", "net451", "net452", "net46", "net461", "net462", "net47", "net471", "net472", "net48")

foreach ($version in $versions) {
    $url = "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.$version"
    $outputZip = Join-Path -Path $env:TEMP -ChildPath "Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.$version.zip"
    $outputFolder = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\"

    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $outputZip
    Expand-Archive -Path $outputZip -DestinationPath $outputFolder\tmp -force
    xcopy "$outputFolder\tmp\build\.NETFramework\*" $outputFolder /E /H /Y
    Remove-Item $outputZip -Force
    Remove-Item $outputFolder\tmp -Recurse -Force
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute VS2022Net4NotCompileFix

[Download Url](https://github.com/MrXhh/VSTools/releases/download/VS2022Net4NotCompileFix_v1.0.0/VS2022Net4NotCompileFix.exe)

this exe file download VS2019 Net4Compile and auto install