# MSB3644 - Missing .NET 4.5 SDK

Tags: c#, .net, sdk

im trying to build my project (which NEED to be wrote in .net 4.5) but since i switched to my laptop it shows this error.

I tried to search for .net 4.5 but apparently the sdk download isnt available anymore (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks).

Does anyone has this sdk?

Where can i download it?

Thanks.

P.S. Im using JetBrains Rider as C# Ide.

Comment: Why not install and target 4.5.1 ?

Comment: I did, but the problem still. To build a project wrote with 4.5.0 i must use 4.5.0 sdk

Comment: well you are using rider...

Comment: Strange. 4.5.1 should be perfectly able to target 4.5.0

Comment: [visual studio - Open .net framework 4.5 project in VS 2022. Is there any workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70022194)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should instead use the 4.5.2 SDK, 4.5.0 was a rushed delivery to meet the targets of other dependent applications from Microsoft. Read between the lines in [Announcing the .Net Framework 4.5.1 Preview](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-the-net-framework-4-5-1-preview/). 4.5.2 quickly superseded the previous version and then as a community we never talked about the two earlier releases.

From a distributable compatibility point of view, .Net 4.5.2 is considered the only viable distributable version because all v4 releases were in-place upgrades, you can't install 4.x versions side-by-side. If your deployment target has any .Net 4.x applications installed, on the balance of probabilities it would already have been updated to 4.5.2

> **[Install .NET Framework for developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/guide-for-developers)**
> All .NET Framework versions since .NET Framework 4 are in-place updates, so only a single 4.x version can be present on a system. In addition, particular versions of .NET Framework are preinstalled on some versions of the Windows operating system. This means that:
>
> - If there's a later 4.x version installed on the machine already, you can't install a previous 4.x version.
> - If the OS comes preinstalled with a particular .NET Framework version, you can't install a previous 4.x version on the same machine.
> - If you install a later version, you don't have to first uninstall the previous version.

*.Net **4.5.2** is considered the **only stable** build of the 4.5 runtime, for legacy development purposes*

> **[.NET Framework 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1 will reach End of Support on April 26, 2022](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-april-26-2022/)**
> The .NET Framework was previously digitally signed using certificates that use the Secure Hash Algorithm 1 (SHA-1). SHA-1 is a legacy cryptographic hashing algorithm that is no longer deemed secure. We are retiring content that were signed using digital certificates that used SHA-1 to support evolving industry standards.
>
> Also see [.NET Framework Releases](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/README.md) to learn about newer releases.

I can't state this strongly enough, you should target 4.5.2, as this is the industry-wide expectation when requested to compile an app in 4.5.

There are similar posts on the Rider support forum, in each case the solution was to copy the SDK files that were already installed elsewhere, the 4.5 SDK was released with the Visua Studio 2012, so you could try looking for an offline installer for that product.

- [.Net Framework Developer Pack install and warnings when opening a solution](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001362039--Net-Framework-Developer-Pack-install-and-warnings-when-opening-a-solution)
- [Using Rider under Windows without Visual Studio: prerequisites](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207288089-Using-Rider-under-Windows-without-Visual-Studio-prerequisites)