# .NET 4.5 project not compiling in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-4.5, .net-framework-version

I have installed Visual Studio 2022 on my PC today.  I have an old app, which targets .NET 4.5.  I see this error when attempting to build/compile the project:

"Error  MSB3644 The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.5 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at [https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks"](https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks%22)

I have read this: https://thomaslevesque.com/2021/11/12/building-a-project-that-target-net-45-in-visual-studio-2022/.  C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5 already exists on my PC.

I have downloaded the .NET 4.5 Developer Pack here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/framework/install/guide-for-developers.  I see this when I attempt to run it:

[image]

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: @Ior, unfortunately that made no difference.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question , I had no idea what to do with it..

Comment: Maybe duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70022194/9334155

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Because you might install a higher version of .net framework firstly, so installer might stop you install a lower version of .net framework

There is another way can try to fix it without reinstalling.

1. Download [Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net45](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.netframework.referenceassemblies.net45) package file
   [image]
2. Modify the file extension name from `microsoft.netframework.referenceassemblies.net45.nupkg` to `microsoft.netframework.referenceassemblies.net45.zip` and Unzip that
3. Copy the files from `build\.NETFramework\v4.5\` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5`
4. Running your project again.

**Note**

This way was also work for .net4.0  [Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net40](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net40/) or other  [older version of .net framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies) which Microsoft might not support in feature

Comment: Thanks.  That did the trick.  +1 for the step by step instructions.

Comment: I wish I could give you a 100 upvotes, if I could.. this solved my problem which I thought was only occurring on my machine as I was new to the project.. and a latest pull somehow screwed it up and its now several hours that I searched and finally reached here..  Thank u very much

Comment: I also used this method for .net 3.5. Works!

Comment: I did the trick, upvote+. thanks

Answer (score 6):

If you want a less hacky way, another option is to download the VS2017 Build Tools and install the .NET Framework 4.5 Targeting Pack only (from the tab Individual Components). This works fine with Visual Studio 2022, since it installs the reference assemblies where they are needed.

[image]

Comment: GAME CHANGER - thumbs up