# Migration problems wth Visual Studio 2022

Tags: entity-framework, migration, visual-studio-2022

Recently my company upgraded Visual Studio from 2019 to 2022, but we have also been tasked to maintain one old project on .NET Framework 4.5. I managed to open it in VS2022 by following instructions in [Open .net framework 4.5 project in VS 2022. Is there any workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70022194/open-net-framework-4-5-project-in-vs-2022-is-there-any-workaround) But there is a problem with creating migration with add-migration command (or update-database for that matter). I get error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetProjectTypes(Project project)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.IsWebSiteProject(Project project)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetTargetDir(Project project)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String configurationTypeName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass3.<.ctor>b__1()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)


Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, **upgrading EntityFramework** NuGet-package to `6.4.4` from `6.2.0` solved the issue for me.