# Issues after VS2022 installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I installed Visual Studio 2022 and cloned one of my "older" projects from Github.

It is based on .NET Framework 4.5.
While cloning it, it asked me if I want to "convert" it to .NET 4.8. I clicked yes.

Now I get these errors:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: [Screenshot from first errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgfyX.png)

Comment: Which workloads did you install with Visual Studio? Can you use VS to create a new 4.5 program?

Comment: What are the first errors in the error list? The last ones are usually the least informative. Do you have the .net framework 4.5 installed?

Comment: I only installed 4.7 and 4.8. I am not able to create a 4.5 program.

Comment: I uploaded another screenshot of the first errors.

Comment: You updated from 4.5 to 4.8. Obiously breaking-changes. Also with what I read, it VS suggested to update because it can't open/work with a .NET 4.5 (there is a workaround). So, either migrate, or follow [Open .net framework 4.5 project in VS 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70022194/open-net-framework-4-5-project-in-vs-2022-is-there-any-workaround)

Comment: I followed the link you sent and also updated Nuget packages. Looks good for now. Thanks for your help

Comment: As a tip, it is not helpful for our english mates here to show the errors in german :D