# Incompatible and unloaded projects in a Visual Studio Solution File (.sln)

Tags: c#, .net, solution

I'm trying to open a solution file in visual studio 2022.
When I'm opening the solution, I'm getting incompatible and unloaded on two of its projects.

[my solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSMDp.png)

As far as I can tell, what I'm experiencing is a .NET framework incompatibility version issue.

I found that the target framework is [4.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTMZI.png).
I downloaded .NET 4.5. When I tried to install it, I got this [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImJWT.png).
I'm totally confused now whether it's a version issue or something else.
What do you think?

Comment: If you right-click and try to "Reload project" do you get a more informative error message?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70022194/open-net-framework-4-5-project-in-vs-2022-is-there-any-workaround

Comment: When I reload the incompatible project I get this [message](https://prnt.sc/5Ev_GGGCtQnW) while for the unloaded project I get the [following](https://prnt.sc/2y-jQursKdjD) @MatthewWatson

Answer (score 1):

.NET Framework 4.5 is no longer supported (support ended 26th April 2022) so it's no surprise your struggling to open it in VS2022. As mentioned in one of the comments (by @Kristin), this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70022194/19214431) should provide some answers.